# Filtering List Query By Another Table's Field (a.k.a Cross-Table or Nested Filtering) in AWS Amplify GraphQL DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

**Which Category is your question related to?**
DynamoDB, AppSync(GraphQL)

**Amplify CLI Version**
4.50.2

**Provide additional details e.g. code snippets**

BACKGROUND:
I'm new in AWS serverless app systems and as a frontend dev, I'm quite enjoying it thanks to auto-generated APIs, tables, connections, resolvers etc. I'm using Angular/Ionic in frontend and S3, DynamoDB, AppSync, Cognito, Amplify-cli for the backend.

WHAT I HAVE:
Here is a part of my schema. I can easily use auto-generated APIs to List/Get Feedbacks with additional filters (i.e. score: { ge: 3 }). And thanks to the @connection I can see the User's details in the listed Feedback items.

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  name: String!
  region: String!
  sector: String!
  companyType: String!
}

type Feedback @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  user: User @connection
  score: Int!
  content: String
}
```

WHAT I WANT:
I want to list Feedbacks based on several fields on User type, such as user's region (i.e. user.region: { contains: 'United States' }). Now I searched for a solution quite a lot like, [#2311](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2311) , and I learned that amplify codegen only creates top-level filtering. In order to use cross-table filtering, I believe I need to modify resolvers, lambda functions, queries and inputs. Which, for a beginner, it looks quite complex.

WHAT I TRIED/CONSIDERED:

1. I tried listing all Users and Feedbacks separately and filtering them in front-end. But then the client downloads all these unnecessary data. Also because of the pagination limit, user experience takes a hit as they see an empty list and repeatedly need to click Load More button.
2. Thanks to some suggestions, I also thought about duplicating the User details in Feedback table to be able to search/filter them. Then the problem is that if User updates his/her info, duplicated values will be out-of-date. Also there will be too many duplicated data, as I need this feature for other tables also.
3. I also heard about using ElasticSearch for this problem but someone mentioned for a simple filtering he got 30$ monthly cost, so I got cold feet.
4. I tried the resolver solution to add a custom filtering in it. But I found that quite complex for a beginner. Also I will need this cross-table filtering in many other tables as well, so I think would be hard to manage. If that is the best-practice, I'd appreciate it if someone can guide me through it.

QUESTIONS:

1. What would be the easiest/beginner-friendly solution for me to achieve this cross-table filtering? I am open to alternative solutions.
2. Is this cross-table filtering a bad approach for a no-SQL setup? Since I need some relationship between two tables. (I thought @connection would be enough). Should I switch to an SQL setup before it is too late?
3. Is it possible for Amplify to auto-generate a solution for this in the future? I feel like many people are experiencing the same issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My former answer can still be useful for others in specific scenarios, but I found a better way to achieve nested filtering when I realized you can filter nested items in custom queries.

Schema:

```
    type User @model {
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        name: String!
        region: String!
        sector: String!
        companyType: String!
        feedbacks: [Feedback] @connection # <-- User has many feedbacks
    }
```

Custom query:

```
    query ListUserWithFeedback(
        $filter: ModelUserFilterInput # <-- Filter Users by Region or any other User field
        $limit: Int
        $nextToken: String
        $filterFeedback: ModelFeedbackFilterInput # <-- Filter inner Feedbacks by Feedback fields
        $nextTokenFeedback: String
        ) {
        listUsers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
            items {
            id
            email
            name
            region
            sector
            companyType
            feedbacks(filter: $filterFeedback, nextToken: $nextTokenFeedback) {
                items {
                content
                createdAt
                id
                score
                }
                nextToken
            }
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            }
            nextToken
        }
    }
```

$filter can be something like:

```
    { region: { contains: 'Turkey' } }
```

$filterFeedback can be like:

```
    {
        and: [{ content: { contains: 'hello' }, score: { ge: 4 } }]
    }
```

This way both Users and Feedbacks can be filtered at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Amplify, and really DynamoDB in general, requires you to think about your access patterns ahead of time. There is a lot of really good information out there to help guide you through what this thought process can look like. Particularly, I like Nader Dabit's https://dev.to/dabit3/data-modeling-in-depth-with-graphql-aws-amplify-17-data-access-patterns-4meh

At first glance, I think I would add a new @key called byCountry to the User model, which will create a new Global Secondary Index on that property for you in DDB and will give you some new query methods as well. Check out https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/key#designing-data-models-using-key for more examples.

Once you have User.getByCountry in place, you should then be able to also bring back each user's Feedbacks.

```
query USAUsersWithFeedbacks {
  listUsersByCountry(country: "USA") {
    items {
      feedbacks {
        items {
          content
        }
        nextToken
      }
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

Finally, you can use JavaScript to fetch all while the nextToken is not null. You will be able to re-use this function for each country you are interested in and you should be able to extend this example for other properties by adding additional @keys.

Comment: Thank you for the great resource, I'll keep investigating. So far from what I gathered @key of byCountry in User model would allow querying Users by country. But I want to List all Feedbacks by User's(who sent the feedback) country. Would it be possible? If you can give me a small example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I edited the original answer with an example and more explanation.

Comment: Here is what I tried: Added byRegion key to User model. Added feedbacks with @connection into User model. Added userFeedbacksId param while calling CreateFeedback. Added custom query: UserByRegionWithFeedback. Now I can filter Users by their region, and receive feedbacks under items object. Now I am able to re-call this api each time nextToken is not null to get all Users in this region. How about feedbacks? I see it returns a nested nextToken but, is there a way to ask for more feedbacks in that user with this api? I don't want to miss any if user has more than 10 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149835/alex)'s answers I implemented the following. The idea is instead of listing Feedbacks and trying to filter them by User fields, we list Users and collect their Feedbacks from the response:

1. Updated schema.graphql as follows:

   ```
    type User
        @model
        @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }])
        @key(name: "byRegion", fields: ["region"], queryField: "userByRegion") # <-- added byRegion key {
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        name: String!
        region: String!
        sector: String!
        companyType: String!
        feedbacks: [Feedback] @connection # <-- added feedbacks connection
    }
   ```
2. Added userFeedbacksId parameter while calling CreateFeedback. So they will appear while listing Users.
3. Added custom query UserByRegionWithFeedback under src/graphql/custom-queries.graphl and used amplify codegen to build it:

   ```
    query UserByRegionWithFeedback(
        $region: String
        $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
        $filter: ModelUserFilterInput
        $limit: Int
        $nextToken: String # <-- nextToken for getting more Users
        $nextTokenFeedback: String # <-- nextToken for getting more Feedbacks
       ) {
        userByRegion(
            region: $region
            sortDirection: $sortDirection
            filter: $filter
            limit: $limit
            nextToken: $nextToken
        ) {
            items {
            id
            email
            name
            region
            sector
            companyType
            feedbacks(nextToken: $nextTokenFeedback) { 
                items {
                content
                createdAt
                id
                score
                }
                nextToken
            }
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            owner
            }
            nextToken
            }
         }
   ```
4. Now I call this API like the following:

   ```
    nextToken = {
        user: null,
        feedback: null
    };
    feedbacks: any;

    async listFeedbacks() {
        try {
            const res = await this.api.UserByRegionWithFeedback(
                'Turkey', // <-- region: filter Users by their region, I will add UI input later
                null, // <-- sortDirection
                null, // <-- filter
                null, // <-- limit
                this.nextToken.feedback == null ? this.nextToken.user : null, // <-- User nextToken: Only send if Feedback NextToken is null
                this.nextToken.feedback // <-- Feedback nextToken
            );

            // Get User NextToken
            this.nextToken.user = res.nextToken;
            // Initialize Feedback NextToken as null
            this.nextToken.feedback = null;
            // Loop Users in the response
            res.items.map((user) => {
            // Get Feedback NextToken from User if it is not null (Or else last User in the list could overrite it)
            if (user.feedbacks.nextToken) {
                this.nextToken.feedback = user.feedbacks.nextToken;
            }
            // Push the feedback items into the list to diplay in UI
            this.feedbacks.push(...user.feedbacks.items);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError.show(error);
        }
    }
   ```
5. Lastly I added a Load More button in the UI which calls listFeedbacks() function. So if there is any Feedback NextToken, I send it to the API. (Note that multiple user feedbacks can have a nextToken).
   If all feedbacks are ok and if there is a User NextToken, I send that to the API and repeat the process for new Users.

I believe this could be much simpler with an SQL setup, but this will work for now. I hope it helps others in my situation. And if there is any ideas to make this better I'm all ears.